# Google не принимает sitemap из-за значения приоритета. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sitemap

Вот такая странная ситуация. Вроде бы в контроллере нормально создается карта сайта, но гугл ругается на столбцы в приходящем файле XML а именно на

```
<priority>1,0</priority>
<priority>0,8</priority>
```

И так на все эти значения. Я думал что дело в цифрах и менял их на 0.5 ли 1, но все равно. Заметил одну вещь что на автогенируемых сайтах для карты сайта на выходе я получаю тоже самое но всюду в приоритетах число разделенное точкой. Вот выкладываю метод что карту генерирует. Там тип дабл и он прописывается точкой но на выходе все равно запятая. В разделители может быть бок?

```
 public ActionResult Sitemap()
    {
        string baseUrl = "https://example.com/";

        // get a list of published articles

        List<string> url = new List<string>()
        {
            "Home/Education",
            "Home/Blog",
            "Home/Contacts",
            "Home/Hedge_Fund",
            "Home/Prop_trading",
        };
        // get last modified date of the home page
        var siteMapBuilder = new SitemapBuilder();

        // add the home page to the sitemap
        siteMapBuilder.AddUrl(baseUrl, modified: DateTime.UtcNow, changeFrequency: ChangeFrequency.Weekly, priority: 1.0);

        // add the blog posts to the sitemap
        foreach (var pages in url)
        {
            siteMapBuilder.AddUrl(baseUrl + pages, modified: DateTime.UtcNow, changeFrequency: ChangeFrequency.Weekly, priority: 0.8);
        }

        // generate the sitemap xml
        string xml = siteMapBuilder.ToString();
        return Content(xml, "text/xml", Encoding.UTF8);
    }


public enum ChangeFrequency
    {
        Always,
        Hourly,
        Daily,
        Weekly,
        Monthly,
        Yearly,
        Never
    }

    public class SitemapUrl
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public ChangeFrequency? ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
        public double? Priority { get; set; }
    }

    public class SitemapBuilder
    {
        private readonly XNamespace NS = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";

        private List<SitemapUrl> _urls;

        public SitemapBuilder()
        {
            _urls = new List<SitemapUrl>();
        }

        public void AddUrl(string url, DateTime? modified = null, ChangeFrequency? changeFrequency = null, double? priority = null)
        {
            _urls.Add(new SitemapUrl()
            {
                Url = url,
                Modified = modified,
                ChangeFrequency = changeFrequency,
                Priority = priority,
            });
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sitemap = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement(NS + "urlset",
                    from item in _urls
                    select CreateItemElement(item)
                    ));

            return sitemap.ToString();
        }

        private XElement CreateItemElement(SitemapUrl url)
        {
            XElement itemElement = new XElement(NS + "url", new XElement(NS + "loc", url.Url.ToLower()));

            if (url.Modified.HasValue)
            {
                itemElement.Add(new XElement(NS + "lastmod", url.Modified.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.f") + "+00:00"));
            }

            if (url.ChangeFrequency.HasValue)
            {
                itemElement.Add(new XElement(NS + "changefreq", url.ChangeFrequency.Value.ToString().ToLower()));
            }

            if (url.Priority.HasValue)
            {
                itemElement.Add(new XElement(NS + "priority", url.Priority.Value.ToString("N1")));
            }

            return itemElement;
        }
```

Код брал от сюда https://developingsoftware.com/sitemap-builder/

Comment: Покажите ваш xml. Дробные числа с точкой, а не запятой, к слову, писать нужно.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kqvxkn

Comment: Запятые на точки замените.

Comment: ну я ж к этому и писал вопрос..наверно лучше перефразировать и испросить как в коде генерировать точки а не запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если глобально, то так:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Или при выводе:

```
Priority = priority.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, при выводе это где?

Comment: @FX_Sektor я ж даже ваш код использовал из метода `AddUrl`.

Comment: глобально определил...работает, гул принял

Comment: @FX_Sektor не стоит глобально переопределять, мало ли где вылезет :)

Comment: @PashaPash с этим согласен. Просто как вариант.

Answer (score 0):

В коде генератора, который вы взяли за основу, нужно явно прописать культуру с разделителем точкой:

```
if (url.ChangeFrequency.HasValue)
{
    itemElement.Add(new XElement(NS + "changefreq", url.ChangeFrequency.Value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLower()));
}

if (url.Priority.HasValue)
{
    itemElement.Add(new XElement(NS + "priority", url.Priority.Value.ToString("N1", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
}
```

Comment: я уже позже переделаю)) ибо надоело дебажить))

Comment: @FX_Sektor потом == никогда